# Как сделать перегрузку операторов

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

Реально ли для объектов этого класса использовать перегрузку оператора + (суммы?) и как это сделать? и имеет ли смысл?

```
class Bus {
    int SeatsNumber;
    int Passengers;
};
```

Comment: Реально. Как только будет понятно, что вы хотите - так и сделаем :) Что такое сумма двух автобусов?

Comment: очень интересно что будет - наверное даблавтобус

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да просто с прицепом - ну, или как "Икарусы" с гармошкой в свое время...

Comment: прицеп не является  автобусом, в таких случаях лучше реализовать пару или массив автобусов, но сойдет и так для тривиальных задач, особенно если  это для тренировки. Но лично я с самого начала старался делать все корректно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь, что это не все определение класса :), и в нем есть и разные методы, поля и модификаторы доступа. Пока же, чтоб не было вопросов, сделаем `Bus` структурой.

```
struct Bus 
{
    int SeatsNumber;
    int Passengers;
};
```

Будем считать, что сумма автобусов - большой автобус с суммой мест и пассажиров.

Тогда все просто:

```
Bus operator+(const Bus& a, const Bus& b)
{
    Bus c;
    c.SeatsNumber = a.SeatsNumber + b.SeatsNumber;
    c.Passengers  = a.Passengers  + b.Passengers;
    return c;
}
```

Вот, собственно, и все.

Ну, а там сами смотрите - нужен ли он вам и имеет ли он необходимую вам семантику...

Comment: Почему то выдает ошибку там где Bus c; no matching func to call for Bus

Comment: Вот, убедитесь, что все нормально - https://ideone.com/juKMnv Смотрите, где ошибка у вас...

Comment: @Maryna Said: Скорее всего в вашем реальном классе `Bus` нет конструктора по умолчанию. Но что у вас там есть и чего нет - отсюда не видно.